# How to search pictures that look like uploaded picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, search, image-processing

I have a database that indexes some thousand pictures. They are convered by the application so I tecnicly change the pictures. Now I want to implement a search that finds pictures that look like a picture given. I could use a timestamp but a slight difference in the picture or the picture metadata would prevent to find the correct image.

So I need a commandline tool that can find pictures that looks like the given picture it would be optimal if this also matches pictues that have another soultion but the same content.

Finaly I will implement this in a ruby on rails application using `system` but I dont think thats a problem if I have a matching tool.

Comment: The correct answer would depend on exactly what you mean by "looks like".  Are these random, full-colour JPGs?  Line art?  Would you count images that are largely the same colour as similar?  Or two images that contain different faces?  Or do the faces need to be similar? This is a hard problem and you will need to reduce the complexity of the question to get a reasonable solution.

Comment: This are JPEGs it should find images that look like the original uploaded just differing in the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution that works for me. A thing that keeps me away from using web based endines is that these pictures contain confident data so I need a Service that works localy and without any connection to an external service.

I installed `isk-Daemon` a Service that comes with a tiny webserver and a SOAP and a XML-RPC engine to work with it. So I also wrote a `IskClient` class that adds the Images to the database and connects them to the Image in the MySQL Database and also runs queries to get similar images. I might build a gem from this class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check [recommendify](https://github.com/paulasmuth/recommendify). From the github page:

> Recommendify is a ruby/redis based recommendation engine - The
>   recommendations can be updated/processed incrementally and on multiple
>   hosts. The worker is implemented in plain ruby and native C.

There is also an example of photo matches [here](http://falbala.23loc.com/~paul/recommendify_out_1.html)

Comment: This wont work because my search shouldnt be based on user data. It should be based on the similarity of the pictures

Answer (score 0):

I think most image similarity engines like [Tin Eye](http://www.tineye.com) use [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) of some form. I'm not sure if there are any ruby libraries out there, but one simple algorithm is to compress the image to, say, 16x16. Do this by averaging a block of pixels into one pixel. Then you can use a sum of differences (or sum of square differences...) to get the delta between any two pictures.